# Need username to disappear when clicking

Tags: android

I am new to android and I was goin through a basic login application in android.
I just wanted to know how to make the "username" disappear when I click the username field like in all the applications we can see.
Now what I have to do is delete the string "username" in the username field and type which I feel is awkward.
Is there anything I can do to implement this feature???

Thanks, in advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Simple  `android:hint="Enter your name"` property in your User Name Edit Text.

It looks like

```
    <EditText
        android:id="@+id/editText_username"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:hint="Enter your name" >   <!-- Here it is  -->
       <!-- Some other rules  -->
    </EditText>
```

[image]

It's called Water mark or Hint in android.

Comment: thanks man...that really worked...
thanks for the screenshot too

Comment: Enjoy buddy.Ask any time.please `Accept` it so its useful to other also :)

Answer (score 0):

What you need is Hint feature in Edittext.

```
<EditText
        android:id="@+id/editText_username"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:ems="10"
        android:hint="Username" >// This will go invisible if you click on edit text


    </EditText>
```

Comment: You dont need anything else for this feature Try it yourself:)

Answer (score 0):

Use `android:hint` property to set the watermarked Username